# Confusion between permutation in algebra and permutation in combinatorics? Are they the same?

Tags: abstract-algebra

When we count the number of elements in a symmetric group, we uses the formula n!. For example, in a symmetric group of 3 elements, there are (123),(132),(1)(23),(2)(13),(3)(12),(1), a total of 6 = 3! of them. Although I can see how this is true in the permutation in combinatorics, I cannot understand why n! gives me the correct number of permutations in a permutation group. As far as I know, (123),(312),(231) are the same in a symmetric group. Thats why I cannot quite understand the formula. My textbook uses the same reasoning as the permutation in combinatorics. Can someone tell me how the formula is derived? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think the formulas of combinatorics are no longer valid when they are needed in some other field (or in daily life, for that matter)?

Comment: The cycle decomposition isn't very useful for counting permutations.

Answer (score 0):

A permutation $\tau : \{1,\dotsc,n\} \to \{1,\dotsc,n\}$ is specified by

- any value of $\tau(1)$
- the value of $\tau(2)$ which lies in $\{1,\dotsc,n\} \setminus \{\tau(1)\}$
- etc.
- the value of $\tau(n)$ which lies in $\{1,\dotsc,n\} \setminus \{\tau(1),\dotsc,\tau(n-1)\}$

Thus, there are $n \cdot (n-1) \cdot \dotsc \cdot 1$ possible permutations.